# Proof that conditional density is Borel measurable

Tags: probability, measure-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

I want to prove that the conditional density $f_{X|Y}: \mathbb {R^2} \to  \mathbb{R}$ defined by 
$f_{X|Y}(x|y)= 
\begin{cases}
\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{Y}(y)} & \text{ if} f_{Y}(y)>0 \\
f_{X}(x) & \text{ otherwise} 
\end{cases}$
 is borel measurable

I know that $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is Borel measurable (by Radon Nikodym) and by Fubini´s theorem $f_{Y}(y)$ and $f_{X}(x)$ are also a borel measurable functions (which we can extend them in $\mathbb {R^2}$)

http://statweb.stanford.edu/~adembo/stat-310b/lnotes.pdf here is a reference about this fact in page 171 but without a proof. A friend of mine told me that this is a consequence about Fubini´s theorem, but I don´t see why this is true

I would really appreciate any hint or suggestion about this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by Borel measurable in this context?

Comment: Borel measurable: inverse image of Borel set is Borel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, $\left\{(x,y)|\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}>\alpha\right\}$ is a Borel set for every $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, and of course $\{(x,y)|f_X(x)>\alpha\}$ is also Borel.

Now we want to argue that $f_{X|Y}$ is Borel. Observe that
\begin{align*}
&\{(x,y)|f_{X|Y}(x,y)>\alpha\}\\
&=\left\{(x,y)|f_Y(y)>0, \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}>\alpha\right\} \cup
\{(x,z)|f_Y(y)=0, f_X(x)>\alpha\}\\
&=\left(
\{f_Y>0\}\cap\left\{\frac{f_{X,Y}}{f_Y}>\alpha\right\}
\right)\cup
\left(
\{f_Y=0\}\cap\{f_X>\alpha\}\right). 
\end{align*}

Hopefully it is clear that all sets here are Borel sets.

Comment: I can see why ${f_{X} > \alpha}$, ${f_{Y} =0}$ and ${f_{Y} > \alpha}$ are Borel sets, but why does ${{ f_{X,Y}(x,y) \over {f_{Y}(y)} }> \alpha}$ is also a Borel set? Is it because the quotient of measurable functions is measurable? I

Comment: Good question! In general case yes, and in this case it can be done in the following way. Since $f_Y$ is nonnegative, ${f_{X,Y}\over f_Y>\alpha}={f_{X,Y}>\alpha f_Y}\cap{f_Y>0}$. Since $f_{X,Y}$ and $\alpha f_Y$ are Borel, the conclusion follows. (The trick to argue ${f>g}$ is a Borel set is the same as the one to argue $f-g$ is a Borel function.) Note that $f_Y$ must be positive in this set, while $\alpha$ could be zero.

Answer (score 0):

Define $F:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}^3$ and $\psi:\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}^3\to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ by
$$
F(x,y)=(f_{X,Y},f_X\circ\pi_x,f_Y\circ \pi_y)(x,y),
$$
where $\pi_x$ and $\pi_y$ are the coordinate maps, and 
$$
\psi(z,v,w)=\frac{z}{w}\cdot 1\{w>0\}+v\cdot1\{w=0\}.
$$
Then $f_{X\mid Y}=\psi\circ F$ is $(\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^2},\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}})$- measurable because the composition of Borel measruable functions is measurable.